# Why does array this take up 1GB of memory?

Tags: node.js

I have files that store game map data, and I am using this function to read the map file and load it into memory when the server starts. Basically 4 bytes at the start tell the server how big the map is, and then each tile on the map has 6 bytes of data. I have roughly 33MB of data stored in multiple files, but when I read them into an array to access from memory, it takes up almost 1GB of RAM. I'm just wondering if something I am doing here is redundant or not needed and causing too much memory to be allocated.

Example: a 256x256 map would have 256 * 256 * 6 + 4 bytes of data

```
let mapData = [];

function loadMapFiles() {
    fs.readdir("./maps", (err, files) => {
        for (let file of files) {
            let pointer = 4;
            fs.readFile("./maps/" + file, (error, data) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                let sizex = data.readUInt16BE(0);
                let sizey = data.readUInt16BE(2);
                let mapNameNumber = Number(file);
                mapData[mapNameNumber] = [];

                for (let y = 0; y < sizey; y++) {
                    mapData[mapNameNumber][y] = [];
                    for (let x = 0; x < sizex; x++) {
                        mapData[mapNameNumber][y][x] = [];
                        mapData[mapNameNumber][y][x][0] = data.readUInt16BE(pointer);
                        mapData[mapNameNumber][y][x][1] = data.readUInt16BE(pointer + 2);
                        mapData[mapNameNumber][y][x][2] = data.readUInt16BE(pointer + 4);
                        pointer = pointer + 6;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned about memory footprints why not keep the data raw and use buffer functions like `readUInt16BE` to read it out if and when it's necessary? Arrays carry overhead, and having a lot of 2D arrays creates a *ton* of overhead.

Comment: @tadman Directly from the file itself rather than store the data in memory?

Comment: You could load it into memory as a Buffer and just keep that around, write accessor methods to read through it and do whatever you want. Node is pretty good at working with raw data like that, there's no reason to expand it into an array. One thing to consider is using a 1D array and 2D emulation when accessing it, that is `mapData[...][y * width + x]` instead.

Comment: JavaScript arrays are usually sized a bit bigger than the content they have in them so that they don't need to be reallocated for each insertion. This padding adds up if you have a lot of them, and given how deeply nested this structure is, it looks like you've got a whole bunch of them.

Comment: Tip: To reduce repetition in code use handles to nested structures, like `let map = mapData[mapNameNumber][y][x] = [ ]` and then use `map` for the remainder of the assignments. Spelling out that long chunk over and over is not only code clutter, it forces JavaScript to navigate that structure top to bottom each time, which is inefficient.

Comment: Tip: Instead of adding things to an array one by one, just declare the contents up-front, like `mapData[...] = [ data.readUInt16E(...), ... ]` which is a lot more clear and resistant to dumb typos.

Comment: I'll try that thanks and look into just storing the buffer

Comment: I think you could wrap that Buffer in a simple class that gives you all the access you need to the underlying data. Never underestimate what ES6 can do with getters and setters!

Comment: Ok I will need to figure out how to do that and try it out